# How to set default value for missing elements in XML using XPath?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xpath

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
    <return>
        <BYTES_LENGTH>12019</BYTES_LENGTH>
        <STATUS>DONE</STATUS>
    </return>
    <return>
        <BYTES_LENGTH>1129</BYTES_LENGTH>
        <STATUS>DONE</STATUS>
        <ERROR_CODE>NO MESSAGE FOUND</ERROR_CODE>
    </return>
</message>
```

I am writing a logic in Node JS using xml2js-xpath library to extract ERROR_CODES and STATUS values in array using the following code -

```
var xml2js = require("xml2js")

const parserXml = new xml2js.Parser();
var val = [];
parserXml.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
STATUS = xpath.find(result, '//STATUS');
ERRORS = xpath.find(result, '//ERROR_CODE');
val.push(STATUS);
val.push(ERRORS);
}
```

Expected Result:

```
[  [ 'DONE', 'DONE' ],  [ '', 'NO MESSAGE FOUND' ]  ]
```

But I am getting this instead

```
[  [ 'DONE', 'DONE' ],  [ 'NO MESSAGE FOUND' ]  ]
```

How can I fix this to include blank value if the element doesn't exist in the XML node. Should I used a different library? What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

With XPath 3.1 (e.g. SaxonJS) you could use the XPath

```
array { 
  array { /message/return/string(STATUS) }, 
  array { /message/return/string(ERROR_CODE) } 
}
```

e.g.

```
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js");

const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
    <return>
        <BYTES_LENGTH>12019</BYTES_LENGTH>
        <STATUS>DONE</STATUS>
    </return>
    <return>
        <BYTES_LENGTH>1129</BYTES_LENGTH>
        <STATUS>DONE</STATUS>
        <ERROR_CODE>NO MESSAGE FOUND</ERROR_CODE>
    </return>
</message>`;

const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`parse-xml(.) ! array { 
  array { /message/return/string(STATUS) }, 
  array { /message/return/string(ERROR_CODE) } 
}`, xml);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you!! Any chance of doing it with existing library?

Comment: @Techidiot, XPath 1.0 doesn't allow you doing e.g. `/message/return/string(STATUS)` so if you want such a feature in the context of XPath 1.0 APIs you need to use the host language, e.g. JavaScript, and select down to `/message/return` and then do `string(STATUS)` for each returned `return` element node. I can't tell on how to integrate that with your existing code/library, I am not familiar with that API.